# Wrap an executable in another executable

Tags: linker, executable

I would like to know if it is possible to include an executable file in another one, and then run it directly from there.
For example, if I am writing a GUI frontend to `clprog.exe`, I would want to have *one* file, `guiprog.exe`, that will run it's internal version of `clprog`.
Assume including the source of the wrapped program in the wrapper program is not an option.

I am more interested in this as a theoretical question, so answers applying to either windows or linux are fine (I am not familiar with other OSs), as well as using any language (C/Java/ASM/other, though I assume if it will be possible in any of these languages it will be ASM and maybe C, and obviously not Java)

Answer (score 0):

First thought that comes to mind is a .NET solution.

If the external executable is a .NET assembly, you could embed it inside of your own project, and at run time load that into an in-memory assembly and execute using reflection.

If the embedded executable was built with .NET I think you would have to extract and temporarily save the executable, execute it as a separate process and then delete it, if you don't want to leave it's trace.